# Angular js get path

Tags: angularjs, spring, path

I have to get .jsp path inside WEB-INF --> flow --> home folder in a back-end spring project and front-end angular.

Actually to find a folder path inside web-inf I'm using this code:

```
    bbApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/meetings', {
                templateUrl: CONTEXT_PATH+'/get/meeting/list.html',
                controller: 'MeetingListController'
            }).
            when('/meetings/:meetingId', {
                templateUrl: CONTEXT_PATH+'/get/meeting/listItems.html',
                controller: 'FolderListController'
                //paramExample: "TEST TEST"
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/meetings'
            });
}]);
```

I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of "CONTEXT_PATH"?

Comment: CONTEXT_PATH = /workbench-mbook-myself